# connecting ucma 3.0 to office 365

Tags: c#, lync, office365

Is it possible to make ucma3.0 talk to my office365?
I want to build a query bot that creates and holds a connection, and responds to questions from other users in my domain.
I started with the publishpresence sample.
Using sipdir.online.lync.com for my FQDN.  Regardless of what I put for the username URI etc it always says the endpoint actively refused my connection attempt.  From what I could gather office365 is running lync 2010 server so it seems like this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to connect with UCMA to Office365. You could however use the [Lync 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18898), this is the Client SDK which you can use to control a your local Lync client.

Depending on your requirements you could run the client in so-called "UI-Suppression" mode to give you an active connection to the Lync server without showing the Lync interface. See [Understanding UI Suppression in Lync SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh345230%28v=office.14%29.aspx).